# Oracle UDT mapping with .Net custom types Package's types mapping issue

Tags: c#, odp.net, user-defined-types, custom-type, odp.net-unmanaged

I am mapping Oracle user defined types to .Net custom types by Oracle Data access unmanaged assembly.

I have followed the article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1261430/Calling-Oracles-Stored-Procedures-and-Mapping-User

I had applied simple scenarios.

1. Created Oracle UDT at schema level i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE STUDENT_TYP IS OBJECT (
STUDENT_ID NUMBER,
STUDENT_NAME VARCHAR(20),
ADDRESS VARCHAR(20),
AGE NUMBER,
BIRTH_DATE DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE STUDENT_TYP_TBL IS TABLE OF STUDENT_TYP;
```

and here is the procedure `GET_ALL_STUDENTS` body

```
PROCEDURE GET_ALL_STUDENTS(P_STUDENTS OUT STUDENT_TYP_TBL)
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT *
    BULK COLLECT INTO P_STUDENTS   
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT  STUDENT_TYP(s.student_id,
            s.student_name,
            s.address,
            s.age,
            s.birth_date,
            null)
    FROM
    student s) ; 
END;
```

Above example is working fine. Above scenario just to explain there is no issue in implementation

2. Now I defined types inside a package e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE STUDENT_PKG 
AS

TYPE  PHONE_TYP_RC IS RECORD (
PHONE_ID  STUDENT_PHONE.PHONE_ID%TYPE,
PHONE_TYPE STUDENT_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE%TYPE,
PHONE_NUMBER STUDENT_PHONE.PHONE_NUMBER%TYPE
);

TYPE PHONE_RC_TBL IS TABLE OF PHONE_TYP_RC;

PROCEDURE GET_ALL_PHONES(P_PHONES_TBL OUT STUDENT_PKG.PHONE_RC_TBL);

END;
```

Following is STUDENT_PKG body

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY STUDENT_PKG 
AS

PROCEDURE GET_ALL_PHONES(P_PHONES_TBL OUT STUDENT_PKG.PHONE_RC_TBL)
IS
BEGIN

SELECT PH.PHONE_ID, PH.PHONE_TYPE, PH.PHONE_NUMBER
 BULK COLLECT INTO P_PHONES_TBL
FROM STUDENT_PHONE PH;

-- END OF GET_ALL_PHONES
END;


--END OF PACKAGE BODY
END;
```

When I add Oracle parameter with all information, I get an Oracle exception

> "OCI-22303: type \"STUDENT_PKG\".\"PHONE_RC_TBL\" not found"

I had already defined the Oracle custom mapping with name `STUDENT_PKG.PHONE_RC_TBL`.

I already tried with following names

- STUDENT_PKG.PHONE_RC_TBL
- STUDENT_PKG
- PHONE_RC_TBL

When I execute `OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);` to get the command text parameters, I get the following information:

[image: Oracle Parameter quick watch]

and when I execute, I get following exception

> OCI-22303: type "KAMI"."STUDENT_PKG" not found

This means there is something tricky to handle the package's udt mapping to .Net class.

Here is my definition of .Net custom class for `P_PHONES_TBL` parameter

```
public abstract class CustomTypeBase<T> :
     IOracleCustomType, IOracleCustomTypeFactory, INullable where T : CustomTypeBase<T>, new()
{
        private bool _isNull;

        public bool IsNull
        {
            get { return this._isNull; }
        }

        public static T Null
        {
            get { return new T { _isNull = true }; }
        }

        public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
        {
            return new T();
        }

        public abstract void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt);
        public abstract void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt);
}

public abstract class CustomCollectionTypeBase<TType, TValue> : CustomTypeBase<TType>,
                   IOracleArrayTypeFactory where TType : CustomTypeBase<TType>, new()
{
        [OracleArrayMapping()]
        public TValue[] Values;

        public override void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection connection, IntPtr pointerUdt)
        {
            OracleUdt.SetValue(connection, pointerUdt, 0, Values);
        }

        public override void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection connection, IntPtr pointerUdt)
        {
            Values = (TValue[])OracleUdt.GetValue(connection, pointerUdt, 0);
        }

        public Array CreateArray(int elementCount)
        {
            return new TValue[elementCount];
        }

        public Array CreateStatusArray(int elementCount)
        {
            return new OracleUdtStatus[elementCount];
        }
}

[OracleCustomTypeMapping("STUDENT_PKG.PHONE_TYP_RC")]
public class PhoneRecord : CustomTypeBase<PhoneRecord>
{
        [OracleObjectMapping("PHONE_ID")]
        public int PhoneId { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMapping("PHONE_TYPE")]
        public string PhoneTYpe { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMapping("PHONE_NUMBER")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public override void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "PHONE_ID", PhoneId);
            OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "PHONE_TYPE", PhoneTYpe);
            OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "PHONE_NUMBER", PhoneNumber);
        }

        public override void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            PhoneId = (int)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "PHONE_ID");
            PhoneTYpe = OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "PHONE_TYPE").ToString();
            PhoneNumber = OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "PHONE_NUMBER").ToString();
        }
}

[OracleCustomTypeMapping("STUDENT_PKG.PHONE_RC_TBL")]
public class PhoneTable : CustomCollectionTypeBase<PhoneTable, PhoneRecord>
{
}
```

and here is stored procedure call:

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("KAMI.STUDENT_PKG.GET_ALL_PHONES", connection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

try
{
            //  OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);
            OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "P_PHONES_TBL",
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object,
                OracleDbTypeEx = OracleDbType.Object,
                UdtTypeName = "STUDENT_PKG.PHONE_RC_TBL",
            };
            command.Parameters.Add(param);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: You need to research. Passing one user defined object vs passing a table/list of them. I think, oracle has a limitation to take only arrays. You can see one of my oracle answers about this. But definitely, research if oracle can do `PROCEDURE X(p_y OUT y_type_TBL)`. It can probably only do `PROCEDURE X(p_y OUT y_type)`. Besides, making this `OUT` makes no sense at all. You can just return `ref_cursor` in this case. Now I am almost convinced oracle does not support `out table of types`

Comment: I did some research. and finally I concluded that Package level record type  which is specific to PL/SQL is even not supported in un-managed assembly. There is limitation at OCI layer. If you try it by using Oracle.dataAccess you will receive OCI-2203 error.